Implicit function theorem without manifolds (Steve Smale article)?
I don't know if this is the right place for this question, if not then please let me know and I will delete it.
In 1974, Steve Smale published an article in the first issue of Journal of Mathematical Economics with the short title "Global Analysis and Economics" which bears on my current research interests. In it, he applies variants of the inverse function theorem/implicit function theorem to a set that is not a manifold and explains that these results "make sense" even in that context. Now please understand, I know who Steve Smale is so I am not saying he's wrong, but this is unlike anything I have seen in my research so I thought someone could help with some thoughts.
In brief, he defines the set $\mathscr{S} \equiv (\bar{P})^m \times S_+$, where $\bar{P}$ is the non-negative orthant of $R^l$ and $S_+$ is the non-negative part of the $l-1$-dimensional sphere $S$. Though his use of the inverse function theorem occurs in a number of places, I will quote one part of the article which should highlight my difficulty:
"We recall that $\psi_u : \mathscr{S} \rightarrow (S)^{m+1}$ is said to be transversal to $\Delta \subset (S)^{m+1}$ provided that for each $s$ with $\psi_u(s) = y \in \Delta$, the image of $D\psi_u(s)$ and $T_y(\Delta)$ (as subspaces of $T_y((S)^{m+1})$) span $T_y((S)^{m+1})$…. Note that although $\mathscr{S}$ is not exactly [italics mine] a manifold, the notion of transversality still makes sense in our context".
"It follows from the implicit function theorem that if $\psi_u$ is transversal to $\Delta$, then $\psi^{-1}_u(\Delta)$ is a submanifold of $\mathscr{S}$ with $\operatorname{codimension} \psi_u^{-1}(\Delta) = \operatorname{codimension} \Delta$. We note also that the notion 'submanifold' of $\mathscr{S}$ is a slight extension of the usual notion. A precise definition would be as follows: Take an open set $\mathscr{O}$ of $\mathscr{S}$ in $(R^l)^m \times S$. Then a 'submanifold' of $\mathscr{S}$ is a subset of $\mathscr{S}$ of the form $V \cap \mathscr{S}$ where $V$ is a submanifold of $\mathscr{O}$." (again, italics mine)."
I hope I haven't violated any copyright, but this article is hard to get hold of online. I have it only because I have hard copies of the first several volumes of JME in my office.
Again, I am posting because I would like to be able to use the IFT et al. on sets like $(\bar{P})^m$, but cannot for the life of me figure out why this works (according to Smale, at least). I realize I haven't yet posed a question, so let me do so now:
Question: In the above passage, the hypothesis is that the function $\psi_u$ is  transverse to $\Delta$ only on the "non-manifold" $\mathscr{S}$, yet Smale is saying the corresponding theorem can be applied as though $\mathscr{S}$ were a manifold. Why? At first I thought Smale was making an implicit assumption that $\mathscr{S}$ was contained in some open set $\mathscr{O}$ that would be a manifold and on which $\psi_u$ would be transverse to $\Delta$. Then you could apply the IFT theorems to $\mathscr{O}$ and simply take the intersection of the resulting submanifold  with $\mathscr{S}$. But it seems that Smale doesn't require that $\psi_u$ satisfy the transversality condition anywhere on $\mathscr{O}$, just on $\mathscr{S}$.
I understand I may have misunderstood something simple, also that I may have left out vital information (just ask), but I can't for the life of me figure out what is going on.

I think the basic idea comes from the transversality extension theorem.  You can make a map transverse with respect to a manifold with boundary by first making it transverse to the boundary, and then (without affecting the intersection with the boundary) making it transverse to the interior.  This idea extends to manifolds with cubical corners, which I think is the context of Smale's paper.

The transversality extension theorem? Now THAT is new to me, I'll search for it. Frankly, it doesn't surprise me that one can extend transversality to a manifold with boundary, but Smale doesn't mention this, at least not directly. I was going down the path of applying transversality and similar results to a neighborhood of $\mathscr{S}$. And, as you point out, $(\bar{P})^m$ isn't even a (smooth) manifold. I actually met Smale when he came to my School to discuss the paper (that's how old I am); I wish I would have asked him then.

The textbook of Guillemin and Pollack does a really nice job of this.  Also Hirsch's.  Both provide clear-enough proofs so that you can see how to extrapolate to manifolds with cubical corners.

Just before I noticed your last comment I was looking at some posts on MSE discussing $\delta$-manifolds and neat manifolds, and one referred to a treatment of manifolds with corners. Unfortunately that reference was a broken link. But your suggestion of G&P and Hirsch is spot on. Thanks much, again, for taking the time to help me out. I'm sure a lot of this stuff was assumed to be too simple (almost "intuitive") by Smale so he didn't spell it out.

@Ryan Budney: Sorry to bother you, but IF you have time could you just address the following question I have: Isn't it true that manifolds with cubical corners (as is $(\bar{P})^m$ in the article) are not smooth manifolds, only topological ones? If so, then don't transversality theorems (including IFT) REQUIRE smooth manifolds, whether with boundary or without? That's what's been bothering me. Thank you in advance for any info you can provide.

Manifolds with cubical corners are not "standard" smooth manifolds.  Yes, they are topological manifolds.  But you can talk about smooth structures on manifolds with cubical corners, and it's far more natural than considering them to be topological manifolds.  If you read Guillemin and Pollack's discussion of smoothness you see that there is a notion of "smooth structure" for any subset of a smooth manifold.  They define smoothness of functions in terms of local smooth extendability.  That's how you talk about manifolds with cubical corners being smooth.

I don't know Smale personally but my presumption (from reading many of his papers) is that while this wouldn't be considered elementary, it's the kind of thing people steeped in geometric-topology understand.  So if he was ever called on his sloppy writing (often he is not) he knew he had a solid foundation to retreat to.

The paper of Laures "On cobordism of manifolds with corners" has convienent references to various papers setting up the basic theory.  The Laures paper appears to be free on-line at JSTOR.

Maybe I misunderstand the point here but isn't the set you are interested in not just a manifold with corners? For these the notions you are searching for are if I remember correctly discussed in the book Outelero-Dominguez, Margalef-Roig: Differential Topology. Along other things they prove versions of the inverse function theorem and the implicit function theorem for manifolds with corners (even in the setting of Banach manifolds)

I worked out the details of transversality for manifolds with corners in my lecture notes on differential geometry. https://drive.google.com/file/d/1_WxFupPeAeHyLAp6bzaJur2ReHuNZemo/view?usp=sharing

@Alexander Schmeding: Yes, but my impression from what I have read is that they (manifolds with corners) were hopelessly complicated. For example, IIRC, there was something about multiple ways to map corners into the model space. Plus, I could find no ready reference to them. However, I very much appreciate the information you have provided.

@Ryan Budney: Aha! That answers a question that arose during my research. I came across a post on MSE that spoke about orthants and mentioned they were topological manifolds, which I knew. But then they spoke of a "smooth structure" modeled on a product of the non-negative real halfspace P, so I made the erroneous inference they were saying orthants were smooth manifolds. I see the subtle difference you have pointed out. Again, many thanks.

@user167131 I think some of the problems with these manifolds actually become better by relaxing the definition.  Helge Glöckner is on the way of doing that with the locally polyhedral manifolds.  You might want to check our recent  https://arxiv.org/abs/2407.05444

There are multiple sensible definitions and treatments of manifolds with corners and their transversality. For my own applications (geometric homology and cohomology, with Friedman and Medina) the best is by Joyce - "On manifolds with corners"

Yes, I've seen that, the introduction I thought was very well organized and explained, going from manifolds to manifolds with boundary to manifolds with corners. Unfortunately, for my purposes, it then veers off to areas that don't bear directly on my particular problem; e.g. regularity in the context of manifolds with corners (unless I am mistaken). Also, I am a bit confused by the model space; in particular, in some treatments the model is a finite product of half-open intervals $[0,\infty)$, in others the product is part half-open intervals and part $R^k$.

Having reviewed the things you wrote the right frame for the question should be manifolds with corners (sets whose differentiable structure is locally modelled on open subsets of the orthants in euclidean space).
Hence your needs should be covered by
J. Margalef-Roig, E. Outerelo Dominguez: Differential Topology 1992, 1
I don't think that there is a public version of the book. It develops first the theory of manifolds with corners (and differentiable mappings between them) in the setting of possibly infinite dimensional Banach manifolds.
The implicit function theorem which should cover your needs is then
Theorem 2.3.11 in 1.
Let $X,Y,Z$ be differentiable manifolds of class $p \in \mathbb{N}_0 \cup \{\infty\}$ $f\colon X\times Y \rightarrow Z$ a map of class $p$ and $(a,b)\in X\times Y$ a point. Suppose that $T^2_{(a,b)} f \colon T_b Y \rightarrow T_{f(a,b)}Z$ is a linear homeomorphism ($T^2$ is their notation for the derivative with respect to the second component, not the iterated tangent map!) and suppose that there are open neighborhoods $V^a$ of $a$ and $V^b$ of $b$ such that $f(V^a\times (V^b\cap \partial Y))\subseteq \partial Z$.
Then there are open neighborhoods $W^a$ of $a$ , and $W^b$ of $b$ and a unique map $q \colon W^a \rightarrow W^b$ such that $f(x,q(x))=f(a,b)$ for $x\in W^a$. Furthermore, $q(a)=b$; $q$ is of class $p$ on $W^a$; for every $x\in W^a$, $T^2_{(x,q(x))}f$ is a linear homeomorphism and $T_xq = - (T^2_{(x,q(x)}f)^{-1}\circ T^1_{(x,q(x))}f$
There is actually a bit more information on the tangent spaces here which I did not repeat as it references earlier numbers in the book. The proof is what you would expect taking into account the boundary conditions (note in particular the added requirements of mapping the boundary into the boundary beyond the usual condition of the tangent maps).

I feel like this should go on the nLab, but I'm not sure where. Not saying you should do it, either!

It seems more like one should create a reference for the various generalisations of manifolds with boundary.  Helge has done lately some cool things with his notion of locally polyhedral manifolds. Michor has his concept of Whitney germs and then there is the very general notion of manifolds with rough boundary.  I have a master student looking at some of these things... need to stop now my family starts staring angrily at me for "working on the weekend ".

Appreciate the effort you put in to write this up, very generous of you. I believe it's as close to a complete answer as I will ever get.
